# Populating information in swift 3 for iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swift3

Let's say I have a textfield where I tell the user to put in their name.  The 'name' then gets populated into all the other appropriate fields.  For example, say the 'other field' is where the person has to sign a document.  Therefore, underneath that 'line' where the person would have to sign the document, the persons name will then be populated there.

How would I go about to fill out information in one part and it would then be populated in all the appropriate fields?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and your delegate will be called when the user enter something in your text field.

1. First set the delegate to self

   ```
   txtField.delegate = self
   ```
2. Use this if you want to change the other fields when the user is done editiing your master field

   ```
   func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
      // change other fields here
      otherField.text = textField.text
   }
   ```